# How to remove all tags from string?

Tags: php, regex, security

I have a string which is containing some tags, like this;

```
$str = '<i>this</i> <u class="anything">is</u> a <b>string</b>';
```

I want this:

```
$newstr = 'this is a string';
```

Actually I want to select everything between `<` and `>` and then replace it with `''`. My target of doing that is defending against *CORS* and *CSRF* vulnerability. How can I do that?

Comment: What if a tag presents inside another tag?

Comment: Couldn't you use php strip_tags? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: @AvinashRaj `<b>anything1 <i>anything2</i></b>`. I want this `anything1 anything2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `strip_tags` function will do that for you

```
<?php
$str = '<i>this</i> <u class="anything">is</u> a <b>string</b>';
echo strip_tags($str);
```

The result would be

```
this is a string
```

---

Also here is REGEX version:

```
echo preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $str); // output: this is a string
```

Comment: Thanks, seems good. +1

Comment: ~100 rep just for answering to my question `:-)` ..! Remember and always answer my questions `:-P`

Comment: Yea it does seem a little excessive. But it makes up for the hundereds of questions that answer a question and never get accepted or upvoted. However its nice to see you have accepted an answer on almost all of your questions